# Documentation/admin-guide/device-mapper/writecache.rst:23: ERROR: Unexpected indentation

Tags: linux-kernel, compilation, kernel, indentation, restructuredtext

While compiling linux documentation using `sudo make htmldocs` I'm getting the following errors

```
/linux_work/linux_stable/Documentation/admin-guide/device-mapper/writecache.rst:23: ERROR: Unexpected indentation.
/linux_work/linux_stable/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-nvdimm:11: ERROR: Unexpected indentation.
/linux_work/linux_stable/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-iio-sx9324:2: ERROR: Unexpected indentation.
```

But when I checked the source code. I couldn't figure out the cause of the error.

Here's **writecache.rst:**

[image]

Here's
Here's **sysfs-bus-iio-sx9324:**
[image]

Here's **sysfs-bus-nvdimm:**

[image]

How can I fix the errors:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This patches solved the issue:

https://lore.kernel.org/linux-doc/1d576ae406d6183321320ffceb9c63a09fa095d3.1660829433.git.mchehab@kernel.org/

https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20220702042350.23187-3-bagasdotme@gmail.com/T/